# Passing and getting parameters by dynamic link in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I make a dynamic link and add a parameter (token or id) there. The logs show that a dynamic link is being created with this parameter, but when i accept link there are deep link with no parameters. It remains the way I put it in Firebase.

```
const buildLink = async () => {
    const link = await dynamicLinks().buildLink({
      link: `https://letssin.app/invite${checklistToken.token}`,
      domainUriPrefix: 'https://letssin.page.link/invite',
      android: {
        packageName: 'PACKAGE_NAME',
      },
      ios: {
        bundleId: 'BUNDLE_ID',
        appStoreId: 'APP_STORE_ID',
      },
    });
    console.log('buildLink - ', link);

    return link;
  };

useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = dynamicLinks().onLink(link => {
      console.log('Link - Foreground -//- ', link);
      handleDynamicLink(link);
    });
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [handleDynamicLink]);

useEffect(() => {
    dynamicLinks()
      .getInitialLink()
      .then(link => {
        console.log('Link - Background/Quit -//- ', link);
        handleDynamicLink(link);
      });
  }, []);
```

Here is the logs

```
LOG  buildLink -  https://letssin.page.link/invite?apn=PACKAGE_NAME&ibi=BUNDLE_ID&isi=APP_STORE_ID&link=https%3A%2F%2Fletssin.app%2Finvite751570f0-ca10-43ef-8b01-b8b692a86cfc

LOG  Link - Foreground -//-  {"minimumAppVersion": null, "url": "https://letssin.app/invite", "utmParameters": {"utm_campaign": "Invite For Checklist & qrcode", "utm_medium": "dynamic_link", "utm_source": "firebase"}
```

Dependencies

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.8.0",
"@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "^12.8.0",
"react": "17.0.1",
    "react-i18next": "^11.11.4",
"react-native": "0.64.2",
"react-native-share": "^7.2.0",
```

Tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can pass and accept this parameter in the application?

Answer (score 1):

the link param should be with a deep link.
you have passed it like:
`https://letssin.app/invite${checklistToken.token}`
but I think it should be something like this:
`https://letssin.app/?in_app=myapp://screen/?invite${checklistToken.token}`

Maybe I'm wrong but it is worth trying.

Comment: Hi there i tried it, but unfortunately, it didn't work.
Do you have any other possible solutions?

Comment: You need to handle in_app param in your app, and extract the deeplink from it .